# Is there a way I can make javascript to not count a particular character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In page 1 I have this html

```
<input value="creditCard" name="creditCard" maxlength="16">
<input value="name" name="name" maxlength="4">
<input type="button" name="submit">

DISPLAY:

1234567891234568

Name

button
```

If I click the `button`, I will go to page 2 and in page 2 I have an edit button. If I click `edit`, I will be directed to page 1 again with the credit card in masked form

```
DISPLAY:

XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-4568

Name

button
```

If for example, I click the `creditCard` input and then the `name` input, the display will look like:

```
DISPLAY:

XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-4

Name

button
```

Since I added "-" it counts as a character and the maxlength is 16 so the value of the input is trimmed to 16 characters only.

Is there a way I can make to not consider "-" as a character to be counted? I can't adjust the maxlength attribute of  the input. It's a business rule. Thank you very much!

Comment: Unclear exactly what you want, length without `-` is `len = ccnumber.replace(/-/g, '').length;`

Comment: You can't have more than the maxlength number of characters in an input. You need to either change the business rule to allow more characters as long as the correct format is input, or don't allow the hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use **JQuery Mask Plugin** for this purpose:

https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

It gives you lot of patterns to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can solve it within this code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" size="4" tabindex="1" maxlength="4" onkeyup="myFunction(this,this.value)"> -
<input type="text" size="4" tabindex="2" maxlength="4" onkeyup="myFunction(this,this.value)"> -
<input type="text" size="4" tabindex="3" maxlength="4" onkeyup="myFunction(this,this.value)">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction(x, y) {
    if (y.length == x.maxLength) {
        var next = x.tabIndex;
        if (next < document.getElementById("myForm").length) {
            document.getElementById("myForm").elements[next].focus();
        }
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```